# How to set attribute value to instance of class at runtime

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm on Enterprise Architect 14. I have a component diagram containing an interface `User` and two classes `Employee` and `Customer`, which both `realize` interface `User`.

[image]

Furthermore I created two instances, one of each class and specified the values of the attributes via `Features & Properties` > `Set Run State...`.

[image]

Next I created a component with 2 attributes, one of type `Employee` and one of type `Customer`. Then I created an instance of the component.

[image]

Now I would like to set run state of the component instance by assigning `ArbitraryUser` to the `Employee` attribute and `ArbitraryCustomer` to the `Customer` attribute of the component instance. According documentation this should be possible (see [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/runtimestate.html)).

> At run-time, an Object instance can have specific values for its attributes, or exist in a particular state. To model the varying behavior of Objects at run-time, use instance values selected from the 'Select ' dialog and run-time states or run-states.

However I could not figure out how to do so. Can someone help me?

Comment: I am having the same issue. According to the documentation http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/instanceclassifier.html I should be able to see a select dialogue which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that is not possible.
I'm not sure what the quote from the help really means, but I've only ever been able to type a value for the run state.

An partial alternative would be to use associations rather than attributes to model such relations. Then you can create a *link* as an instance of the association to relate instances of `Employee` or `Customer` with instances of a `ArbitraryComponent`.

This solution doesn't work for datatypes, but it seems a bit far fetched to start modelling instances of datatypes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your alternative solution would be to associate `ArbitraryCompoonent` with `Customer` and `Employee` class, correct? `ArbitraryComponentInstance` would then be associated with the corresponding instances `ArbitraryCustomer` and `ArbitraryUser`. Correct?

Comment: Yes something like that, although I'm now a bit puzzled seeing that you have a Component and Component instance instead of a Class and Object. I've only ever used attributes and associations on Classes, but it might be valid to use those on Components as well.

Comment: The idea behind the class diagram was to model new attribute types `User`, `Customer` and `Employee`, that could be used for example in components

Comment: I just checked the UML specs, and it turns out a component is actually a specialization of class, so it is definitely valid UML.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Validation in EA succeeded too.